# Get changes from featurebranch checkout from preprod in to develop branch

Tags: git, git-flow

In my repos i have

- `branchFeatureA` checkout from `preprod`. Then all commit of `branchFeatureA` will be merge to this branch
- `develop` is branch for all developers push codes of all features. and I uses `develop` branch for QA to test all features.

What's the best way to merge `branchFeatureA` into `develop` with only changes from `branchFeatureA`

Comment: **In strict-git terms**, you could cherry-pick the changes you want into a branch started from `develop`, then you can merge that branch into `develop`. That will have _no_ relation to the original branch where it was developed.

Comment: oh thanks @eftshift0 . Seem there is no way except cherrypick the changes into `develop` for QA to test.  I create `featurebranchA` from `preprod` cause i only want to release this branch instead of all `develop`.

Answer (score 0):

To "rebuild" `branchFeatureA` that was created from `preprod`, to make it look like it came off of `develop` instead, conceptually, you would make a new branch, and then cherry-pick each of the *new* commits from your old branch to the new one. You can actually do that if you'd like, or you can use an advanced rebase in a single command:

```
git rebase preprod branchFeatureA --onto develop
```

In words that says:

> Take all of the commits on `branchFeatureA` that are not reachable by `preprod`, and replay them, one by one, onto `develop`.

Since you tagged this with [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram), I'm going to assume your branch `preprod` is acting like a `release` branch. Note in Git Flow it's actually OK to merge a `release` branch down to `develop`, even before you release to production and then merge `release` into `master`. If the reason you are switching the branches is because you originally planned on merging `branchFeatureA` into `preprod`, but then changed your mind and decided to merge into `develop` instead, then it's completely fine to switch it. However, if you already merged `branchFeatureA` into `preprod` and now you also want to have that code in `develop` earlier than it would normally get there after a release to production, then it would actually be better to simply merge `preprod` into `develop` instead of rebasing your feature branch. If you rebase (or cherry-pick), then you will end up with two copies of those commits in your repository, which is generally undesirable compared to just one. Note this is only true if you're going from `preprod` to `develop`; you can do that anytime you wish. However, you can't go the other way; if you merged your feature branch into `develop` but then decided you want to release it early, you can't merge `develop` into `preprod` as that would bring in other features as well.